# Calling setState in callback of setState generate a weird bug that prevents input's value to be updated by onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a list of input to generate dynamically from an array of data I retrieve from an API.

I use .map() on the array to generate each of my input, and set `value={this.state.items[i]}` and the `onChange` property (with a modified `handleChange` to handle change on an array properly).

Now, I set in my constructor `this.state = { items: [{}] }`, but since I don't know how many items are going to be generate, `value={this.state.items[i].value}` crash since `this.state.items[n]` doesn't exist.

The solution is then to set each `this.state.items[i] = {}` (using Array.push for example) first, and then generate all the inputs.

```
var apiData = [{ value: "" }, { value: "" }]
this.setState({
    items: apiData,
    inputs: apiData.map((v, i) => {
        return <input key={i} value={this.state.items[i].value}
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeArray(e, i)} />
    })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qzb17dut/38/

The issue with this approach is that `this.state.items` doesn't exist yet on `value={this.state.items[i].value}` and we get the error `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`.

Thankfully, setState() comes with a handy second argument that allows to do something only once the state is set. So I tried this:

```
var apiData = [{ value: "" }, { value: "" }]
this.setState({
    items: apiData,
}, () => this.setState({
    inputs: apiData.map((v, i) => {
        return <input key={i} value={this.state.items[i].value}
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeArray(e, i)} />
    })
}))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qzb17dut/39/

(**Update**: Please have a look at this example that better illustrate the use case: https://jsfiddle.net/jw81uo4y/1/)

Looks like everything should work now right? Well, for some reason, I am having this very weird bug were `value=` doesn't update anymore like when you forget to set `onChange=` on an input, but here `onChange=` **is still called**, `value=` is just not updated making the field remaining not editable.

You can see on the jsfiddle the problem for each method. The first one doesn't have the state set yet, which would allow the input to be edited, but crash because the state value was not yet set. And the second method fix the first issue but introduce this new weird bug.

Any idea about what I am doing wrong? Am I hitting the limit of react here? And do you have a better architecture for this use case? Thanks!

Comment: Please read https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state. Minimal representation of UI State should not include `inputs` because you already have `apiData` in state. You are repeating things in state.

Comment: The reason I put the inputs in state is that in my real use case, there are several options and depending on what is selected, the list of input in the widget changes. It needs to be in the state since it is dynamic, not a one time loading action. Except if I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this approach instead, where you set the state of the API values only and then, generate the input based on the state from the render `via Array.prototype.map` like so

```
 constructor (props) { 
   this.state = {items: []}
  }

async componentDidMount(){
   const apiData = await fetchApiData()
   this.setState({items: apiData}) 
 }

 handleChange = (value, index) => {
    const items = this.state.items;
    items[index].value = value;
    this.setState({ items });
  };

  updateState = () => {
    const items = this.state.items;
    items.push({value: ''}); // default entry on our item
    this.setState({ items });
  };

 // here ur state items is exactly same structure as ur apiData
  onSubmit =()=> {
  console.log('this is apiData now', this.state.items)
  }

  render () {
     <button onClick={this.updateState}>update state with inputs</button>
      <button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Submit</button>
     {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
              <input
                key={index}
                value={item.value}
                onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.value, index)}
              />
            ))}
    }
```

here is the codesandbox code for it

https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-forest-t942o?fontsize=14

with this, it will generate the input based on the items on the state, which in turns have the click handler which updates the state.

Comment: Yup, of course this works, but I would need to copy data and I'm trying to avoid this. This is the reason why I was spending time on this architecture :)

Comment: @Adrien copy data in terms of setting state from the previous items state?

Comment: I mean I would need to copy from `this.state.items[i]` to `apiData[i].value` later in the process if that makes sense?

Comment: oh, you can simply just make your item state look like ur `apiData[i].value` updating the answer to show that. And you can set the initial value from ur `apiData` via`componentDidMount`

Comment: @Adrien updated the answer to show the on change handler `updateState` to maintain the same format as apiData

Comment: It is very interesting! Basically, it is a very bad idea to put React elements directly in the state, since other than that, the code is identical! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Well if I understand correctly, apiData is assigned to state.items and then also used to generate the inputs array. That means that for your purpose apiData and state.items are equivalent. Why don't you use the third map argument like:

```
var apiData = [{ value: "" }, { value: "" }]
this.setState({
    items: apiData,
    inputs: apiData.map((v, i, arr) => {
        return <input key={i} value={arr[i].value}
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeArray(e, i)} />
    })
});
```

or the apiData array directly?

Comment: Or even `... value={v.value} `

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this code would not work and would make the input not editable since `value=` needs to be linked to the state.